# How to to get normal distributed neural network output

Tags: regression, neural-networks, normal-distribution, standardization

I am trying to build a neural network that predicts a pair of latitude / longitude coordinates following a previous pair of latitude and longitude (highly simplified). The latitudes and longitudes from my training dataset are approximately normal distributed, so I decided to go by best practices and standardise my inputs (scale them to a mean of 0 and standard deviation of 1).

This works just fine, but now I am wondering what activation function I should use on the last layer of my network. I would expect my outputs to be of the same order of magnitude (mostly within [-1, 1] but a noteworthy number outside), so I can convert them back to actual latitudes and longitudes using the inverse of my standardisation scaler.

I considered sigmoid at first, but that should only give me values in the fourth quadrant within the "border" drawn by the standard deviation of the inputs as I can only get positive outputs up to 1. Next, I considered tanh, which solves the quadrant problem but still limits me to outputs within the "standard deviation border".

By "standard deviation border" I mean the somewhat rectangular shape around the mean (lat,lon) point of two times the standard deviation on both axis.

I hope this makes more sense. Please tell me, if I am entirely on the wrong track. Maybe outputting actual latitudes and longitudes is the better idea in the first place?

Comment: Do you have a particular reason why you expect the predictions to be normally distributed? If your pairs of inputs and outputs are completely unrelated, then the best any algorithm can do is predict the training average *for every input*, so the output will just be a single point. You can construct data with pretty much any shape in the output.

Comment: I expect them to be normally distributed because my inputs are. My training data are coordinates of the movement of cabs in San Francisco. I want the trained network to produce new, but similar (plausible) movement. Therefore, when my training data is normally distributed, I expect my outputs to be, too. I hope I am making sense.

Comment: "I expect them to be normally distributed because my inputs are." This assumption does not hold. Neural networks will stretch and reshape the inputs in order to get a good fit to the data -- even if that means changing the distribution of the output. But the distribution of the outputs is usually irrelevant; what problem are you trying to solve, and how does a normal distribution of outputs help to solve it?

Comment: If you are not predicting something, but attempting to create "similar" data, then [tag:generative-models] may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Okay, I get that. I think I might not actually want the outputs normally distributed, but only within the same order of magnitude, if that makes sense. I rephrased the original question and I hope it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use any activation function in the last layer (or, just use the identity activation function). This would be using a neural network regressor to predict the latitude and longitude directly.  So every sample has a corresponding 2-d vector $(lat, long)^T$ and when the network predicts it predicts a similar 2-d vector, where each element of the vector is continuous.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just for clarity: You are proposing to train against actual unscaled latitudes and longitudes, correct? Am I right in thinking that raining against standardised outputs is possible, too, and might be an option for hyperparameter exploration?

Comment: You are proposing to train against actual unscaled latitudes and longitudes, correct? Yes, or you can center and scale them and then transform back into the unscaled ones after

Comment: Am I right in thinking that raining against standardised outputs is possible, too, and might be an option for hyperparameter exploration?  It is possible, not sure what you mean by an option for hyperparameter exploration